# SASS/LESS/SCSS nesting vs single class declarations

Tags: css, sass, less

I have an html layout like so

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
            <p class="p1"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And using a preprocessor CSS library like LESS/SASS/SCSS, I can nest my classes accordingly:

```
.one {
    .two {
        .three {
            p.p1 { }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, should I? Or is it better to do:

```
.one {

}

.two {

}

.three {

}

.p1 {

}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want...

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. This is *not* just a matter of opinion. There are good, *technical* reasons as to why you might or might not nest your selectors in Sass or Less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend not nesting when you don't need to. It will make your selectors overly specific and harder to overwrite later, should you need to.

You can read more about it here: http://chrisltd.com/blog/2013/05/dont-deeply-nest-sass-less/